# Connecting to GRPC Container in Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, grpc, k3s

For the current stage of my project, I have deployed a docker image of a server using GRPC to K3s for additional fault tolerance and to allow my clients to connect with a DNS instead of IP

My Deployment looks like:
vei-deployment.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vei-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server-pod
```

my service .yaml vei-service.yaml looks like:

```
  ---
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        konghq.com/protocol: grpcs
      name: server-pod
      labels:
        app: server-pod
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
        - name: grpc
          port: 50051
          targetPort: 50051
      selector:
        app: vei-deployment
```

and my ingress .yaml

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: server-pod
  annotations:
    konghq.com/protocols: grpc,grpcs
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
spec:
  tls:
  rules:
    - host: kong.gamov.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-pod
                port:
                  number: 50051
```

According to Kubernetes, the deployment and svc seem to be running correctly. However, when I try to connect to the pod from the cluster using the following code.

```
host = 'server-pod'
server_port = 50051

# instantiate a channel
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    '{}:{}'.format(host, server_port)
)
```

I receive an error that the DNS resolution has failed, specifically:

```
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "DNS resolution failed for server-pod:50051: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=server-pod is_balancer=0: DNS server returned answer with no data"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:DNS resolution failed for server-pod:50051: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=server-pod is_balancer=0: DNS server returned answer with no data {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2022-11-13T21:06:40.820494174+00:00"}"
```

All of the nodes are running correctly, communication is occurring from within the kubernetes cluster, all of the kube-system pods are also running correctly. Communication works correctly when the server is running in a Docker container. I don't not know what is incorrect in this. Is is a problem with ingress control.

Comment: The Service and Pod labels don't match; the Service binds to a pod labeled `app: vet-deployment` but your Pods are labeled `app: server-pod`.  I'm not sure if this would cause a DNS error, but it would definitely cause connections to not go through.

Comment: (Ingress won't work here because your service isn't exposing an HTTP endpoint.  I'd `kubectl delete` the Ingress object and delete its YAML in source control.  But it's also not used for connections within the cluster.)

Comment: I tried both fxing the service binding from vei-deployment to server pod, and deleting the ingress as well. The problem is the same.